# ng_change doesn't copy time value of angular-moment-picker into other fields

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angularjs-ng-change, angular-moment

I have a dynamically generated form with a time field which is filled in with `angular-moment-picker`. I want this value to be copied to the other time fields using a function assigned to `ng_change`. Currently this function is not called however my input field includes `ng_change`. When I don't use `moment-picker` then value is copied without any issues. 
input field:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mymodels.Model[i].Time,
                        new
                        {
                            @class = "form-control",
                            ng_Model = "Model_Time" + (i + 1),
                            ng_change = "copyTime(" + (i + 1) + ")",
                            moment_picker = "Model_Time" + (i + 1),
                            format = "LT",
                            locale = "nl",
                            ng_model_options = "{ updateOn: 'blur' }",
                            set_on_select = true
                        })
```

Copy function:

```
  $scope.copyTime = function (index) {
        console.log("Check if function is called");
        $scope.Model_Time2 = $scope.Model_Time1;
        $scope.Model_Time3 = $scope.Model_Time1;
        $scope.Model_Time4 = $scope.Model_Time1;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker), it has its own function called `change`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mymodels.Model[i].Time,
                        new
                        {
                            change = "copyTime(" + (i + 1) + ")"
                            // ...
                        })
```

That said, if angular-moment is using `ngModelController` underneath to update the model, I'd have expected `ng-change` to work as well since it is invoked automatically once the model has changed. Maybe it doesn't play nice with `ng-model-options`?

Comment: It works however not as I want to. It copies values but then every field is dependent on others, when I change value in second time field values in all others are changed too. I want to set value for all only when value is changed in first time field, so the rest is still editable independently from others.

Comment: Seems like your question was about the function not firing, which is solved. If the function actually shouldn't be fired for certain controls, or its implementation should be changed, maybe that's a separate issue.